# nginx+uwsgi+python2.7 come up with a bottleneck that can not pass 20000x40000 benchmarking

Tags: python, apache, nginx, benchmarking, uwsgi

i'm coming up with a bottleneck that my server can't pass a 20000x40000 benchmark test no matter what adjustments i made.
the server have 128G Ram and with an Xeon 6 core cpu, centos5.6-64bit, in a good shape.

i try combinations including:

```
nginx + uwsgi + python2.7
nginx + apache + mod_wsgi + python2.7
apache + mod_wsgi + python2.7
```

none of them could make through the apache benchmarking:

```
ab -c 20000 -n 40000 (without -k)
```

and coincidentally, almost all tests failed around 32000 requests

detail about nginx and uwsgi:

nginx:

```
worker_processes  24
use epoll
worker_connections  65535
```

uwsgi:

```
listen 2048
master true
workers 24
uwsgi -x /etc/uwsgi_conf.xml --async 256 --file /var/www/example.py &
```

anybody have any idea about it?
thanks in advance to any possible solutions and suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowing such amount of concurrent connections on a single system requires a huge list of kernel tuning and probably you will never be able to manage such load in production.

First of all you have to increase the number of ephemeral port, the socket backlog queue, the number of allowed file descriptor per process and so on...

In addition to this (that should be already enough to stop such unrealistic test) you should increase the number of async core in uWSGI to 20k. Nothing wrong with taht (each core consume less than a page of memory), but you will end with at least 40k opened socket in your system.

This is for nginx+uwsgi.

With Apache you will end with 20k processes or threads, which is even worse than the 40k opened sockets.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply. i increased the file-max to 13076469, local_port_range from 1024 65535, somaxconn to 1048576, i believe is quite enough, but no luck to the test

Comment: and i increased nginx worker, worker_connection, uwsgi asyn core, still no luck

Comment: one more question: is the 20kx40k bench ridiculous? i thought a 20k concurrency is not a big number

Comment: 20k is more-or-less tolerable for serving static files. Serving apps is another matter. You will end with non-blocking programming, and i suppose you will need to connect to some form of database (so another 20k opened socket, and we are at 60k + the load on your db server, that in mysql, as an example, will mean 20k new threads). You could try with a more recent kernel/distro, but if you need such requisite for your app you should start thinking heavily about clustering.

Comment: database connection could be saved by unix socket files, that's what i'm currently implementing. i tried to serve static files, and a 20kx300k bench worked well. but it still can not pass a 20kx30k app bench. thank you very much for your answer, it helped a lot!